# How do I clone git private repository in eclipse?

Tags: git, authentication, github, git-clone, private-repository

[image]

While trying to do that, I keep getting this error but my URL is correct. However, when I tested with public repo it works fine

Answer (score 4):

Since April 2021, no more password is accepted when authenticating Git operations on GitHub.com: you would need to use (or cache) a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

Since a public repository does not require authentication when cloning, you would not see the same error message.

So: Double-check what password is used.
Said password could be cached in your Windows Credential Manager: see what `git config credential.helper` returns.

If it is manager-core, open the windows Credential Manager, and see if you have a `github.com` entry.
If you do, check the cached password.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However this is the first time I'm trying on git and there's no password cached in my windows credential manager. 

I just followed, PAT link you provided and created a token in my account. Now should I use PAT token in the place of password to clone the private repo in eclipse?

Comment: @BharathKashyap Exactly: use the PAT as password for your Git operation.

Comment: I used PAT as password to clone the repo and it works now. Thanks for your response, much appreciated !

Comment: @BharathKashyap Great! Well done.

Comment: @bha is there anything missing to this answer, that you originally accepted?